# UILabel and UITableView CGrectMake reframing - iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uilabel, cgrectmake

I have a NavigationControllers A and a UIViewController B . A has a label and below that is the UITableView. When navigate from A to B and navigate back from B to A, I have my label and table view reframed. I have tried setting the frame through code in ViewWillAppear method. Yet i dont have it in its exact frame. What is the basic thing i'm missing here?

```
[self.labelUser setFrame:CGRectMake(71, 73, 179, 20)];
[self.customersTable setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 102, 320, 421)];
```

Autolayout being used.. But yet this i'm not able to resolve. I have attached the images for the same

![enter image description here][2]    ![enter image description here][3]

EDIT : Code for KVO to check frame values and to change the frame back to the original

in ViewDidLoad

```
[labelUser addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:NULL];
```

and then

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                  ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                   context:(void *)context {

    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"frame"]) {
        NSLog(@"changed %@ %@", NSStringFromCGRect(labelUser.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(customersTable.frame));
        if (![NSStringFromCGRect(labelUser.frame) isEqual:NSStringFromCGRect(CGRectMake(71, 73, 179, 20))]) {

            [labelUser removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame"];
            [self.labelUser setFrame:CGRectMake(71, 73, 179, 20)];
            [self.customersTable setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 102, 320, 421)];

        }

    }
}
```

pushing the view like this

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToOrd" sender:self];

}
```

Also tried the KVO method.. But no luck... Any suggestions??

Story board image

[image]

Comment: Do you use xib or storyboard ?

Comment: If I was you , I will use key-value observing to observe the label's frame.

Comment: Hi I tried that and saw that the height is getting changed during the navigation. Dunno why but i tried reframing it again and doesnt work..

Comment: Set a breakpoint and you will see the call stack. What does it say? You can also print the old value and new value.

Comment: I have printed old and new value... old value {{71, 73}, {179, 20}} changed new value is {{71, 73}, {179, 0}} ... i'll add the code what i have done to the question.. please check the edit

Comment: You should check the last callback and find out who modify the label's frame. In your code, perhaps you removed the observer when it first called.

Comment: its happening in the 1st call back itself.. Always.. hence i removed it... How do i find who modified it?

Comment: Add a breakpoint in `observeValueForKeyPath...` and analysis the call stack but it won't help every time.

Comment: i did it and still not able to find how to reframe it

Comment: Just tell me, what is the purpose of using 2 navigationControllers? Can't you just use a single navigation controller and push a UIViewController on it ? The spacing makes me think that the navigation controllers are being nested. Share the push/didSelectRowAtIndexPath code please.

Comment: sorry my bad... they are not two nav controllers.. A is a Nav controller and the other viewcontroller is pushed... I have added the code...

Comment: Could you put a screenshot of your B controller's Storyboard and its view hierarchy? Something like this to have an idea of what are you trying to achieve: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22775114/1049134 You shouldn't need any code for something so simple.

Comment: please provide storyboard's screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using iOS 7 , this is because the from XCode 5 and above AUTOLAYOUT has been added by default to projects. So the frames in Storyboard are eventually converted to frames which are constant. So if you change frames it might take effect for that moment but when view  loads again it would take the frames back from storyboard and not the frames you have changed.

So the solution for your problem is you have to manually add constraints and only change constraint constants and not the frames.Apple is going to ditch frames very soon,so start learning about Autolayout.

PS : Your code will work as you intended if you uncheck "use Autolayout" option in inspector of your storyboard.

Comment: Hi... AutoLayout is not present for iOS 6 and below and hence not using it... and one more thing is that i'm not changing or setting the frame anywhere other than storyboard. The code i have added is just to make sure that the label retains its frame.

Comment: I think you might not have noticed that Autolayout was introduced in iOS 6. Please check your Storyboard setting and and also specify what version of XCode you are using.

Comment: Ok... if your deployment target is iOS 5 and above then you cannot use AutoLayout since it was introduced from iOS6 onwards is what i meant. I'm using Xcode 5.. So my deployment target is iOS 5 and hence i cant use auto layout.

Comment: I have checked the way you said like for XCode 5 and deployment to iOS 5,It does take Autolayout by default as i had answered. Open Storyboard -> and Check first tab in Inspector as whether Autolayout is enabled.I am damn sure its enabled.First Please do check it and then reply.

Comment: Ok... Please go to build settings ... change ur deployment target to iOS5.. and then try to enable auto layout and see if you can enable.. It'll give u an error...

Comment: I'm not using AutoLayout is the key here. AutoLayout was introduced from iOS 6 as u said but if u want ur application compatible for iOS 5 and above , then you can use auto-layout since auto-layout is not present in iOS 5 .... Autolayout works only from iOS 6 and above not for iOS 5 and above...

Comment: Yes , I can understand what you mean. But it does'nt show up any error for me in latest two xcodes { 5.0.2 (5A3005) } ,  { Version 5.0 (5A1413) }

Comment: Can you send me your code so that i can see if i can help out.