# I want to be able to scroll a UITableViewCell left and right using a Storyboard. Is this not possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uistoryboard

I've tried every thing I can think of, and nothing is working.

Similar to the effect in iOS 7's Mail.app, I want to be able to slide the cells of my table view right and left. I want to be able to do this in a Storyboard and Auto Layout, as most of my app is done with those. I understand scroll views with Storyboards calculate their contentSize by the constraints of their subviews.

With that, I've predominantly tried two strategies. The first, just have a label in the scrollview that I can slide right or left. I set it to be stuck to the top of the scroll view and the bottom, but 300pts on either side of the label to allow the scroll view to calculate its contentSize. This pushes the label enormously to the right so I can't see it when the table loads.

Option two, the preferable one, is to put a UIView in the scroll view, and then put the label and whatnot within that so they can be all positioned as a group with their UIView parent. I've tried simply setting the UIView here, setting it to be stuck to the top and bottom of the scroll view, the width is set to 320, while the left and right side are 320 away from the edges.

This complains that there's no height constraint, but I told it to stick to the top and bottom of the scroll view. How does that not count? If the cell size grows, the scroll view is set to grow with it, and as a result I want the inner view to grow in height as well. It also complains of the position horizontally for some reason.

[image]

[Here's an example project with all the constraints mentioned.](http://cl.ly/0V0g2O1I1Z3W)

What on earth is going on? Is this an impossible task?

Comment: Do you mean swipe single cells left/right to reveal options or to have an "horizontal" table view?

Comment: Swipe cells left/right. Swipe isn't the right word though as I want interactive, more like a pan. As I said, like iOS 7's Mail.app.

Comment: I have the same problem, hope someone can provide a solution.

Comment: I don't think you can create animation in Storyboards so there's no way to achieve what I think you're looking for without writing some code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would add a scroll view to each cell's contentView.

I would set the scroll view width to one-third of the with of the cell, set paging enabled and not to clip its subviews.

[image]

Then add a "real" content view inside with the width of the cell that will hide the underlying buttons.

Finally you have to set programmatically the correct `contentSize` (width of the cell) and initial `contentOffset` (one-third of the width).

You can also play with the scroll view `contentInsets` to further adjust it.

---

Sample Nib code [here](https://gist.github.com/rivera-ernesto/11359440).

Comment: Would it be possible to upload this project? I'm having trouble replicating it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think the answer is that what you want to do is impossible in pure Storyboards. You'll need code to provide animation or a transition between Views.

Answer (score -2):

Your question is if you can make an `UITableViewCell` draggable?

If I understood right the answer, you could get 2 content view:

1. The back view
2. The draggable view

Then, you should add a custom `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to `UITableViewCell`, and with this you detect how many pixel you drag the cell (only on x values if you want only drag on x values), and finally you only should update draggable view's origin.x with the pan value.

If it's not what you are looking for, please be more precise in question and I'll give you a correct answer :)

Comment: Apple recommends using a UIScrollView. I'd like to do it that way as well, as outlined in the question as I don't have to mess around with gesture recognizers, the scroll view will handle that.

Comment: Do you know how to make an `UITableViewCell` subclass, right?

Comment: `UITableViewCell` has the properties of every `UIView`, so you can add every subview, for example an `UIScrollView`. Have you already written some code to try it?

Comment: I'm aware of that. Have you not read the question? This is in regards to using it in a Storyboard environment. There should be no code.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, but my question was if you could give me more infos about your project, so that I could give you a more precise answer.

Comment: My whole project is attached at the bottom. I've outlined the constraints I have, and included a screenshot of all of them. I'm not sure what you're missing exactly.

Comment: You can not achieve animation type of effects without code (AFAIK.)